# How can I find out what kind of card reader I have?

Tags: hardware, card-reader

I have a card reader in my HP Mini netbook, but when I insert a card in it, the card is not recognised at all, and so not mounted. Does anyone know which kind of processor is used, and how I can get it working?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can find the type of card reader by running the following command:

`lspci & lsusb`

One of them is bound to be it. Once you have the info, you can ask a question specifically about it.